# Text widget with self-adjusting height based on interactively entered text?

Tags: java, widget, swt

Using SWT and Java, I have a Text widget defined which is set for multi-line and wrap properties. I added a listener which will monitor any changes to the text inside this text widget, and I want the height of the widget to automatically change if the user adds a new line of text, or if the text wraps around to the next line. So, I want all of the text visible in the text widget if the user adds new text, or deletes text. Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
mTextValue = new Text(compositeEditor, SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.MULTI);
mTextValue.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
mTextValue.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));

mTextValue.addListener(SWT.Modify,new Listener() 
{
   protected int lines=1;

   public void handleEvent(Event e) 
   {                
     Text text = (Text) e.widget;   
     int newlines = text.getLineCount();                  

     if (newlines!=lines) 
     {
    lines=newlines;
    height = lines*16;
    width = 240;
    text.setSize(width,height);
    text.getShell().pack(true);
 }
}
});
```

Now, this seems to work ok if I add a single line of text and press the return key to add the next line. The text widget grows in height when I add lines of text, and shrinks in height when I remove lines. Just as I want. But, when I have text that wraps around and I try to add a new line, the text widget is resized in width also. I want to keep the width fixed, and only self adjust the height.

Can anyone offer a suggestion to how I can have the text widget self adjust its height to fit all of the entered text, but keep the width of the text widget always fixed at a prescribed value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because pack() re-computes the preferred size. I don't see any direct way to set the prefered width to constant. But you may try overriding `computeSize` method so that you pass fixed width as hint to super class.

i.e

```
public Point computeSize(int wHint,
                         int hHint,
                         boolean changed)
{
    return super.computeSize(240, hHint, changed);
}
```